# Maven release plugin fails to release version

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I have multi module project where in every pom.xml I have same parent pom.xml.
I'm using maven-release-plugin in order to make a tag in svn with following part of pom.xml of parent

```
<profile>
            <id>make-tag</id>
            <modules>
                <module>../module1</module>
                <module>../module2</module>
                <module>../module3</module>
                <module>../module4</module>
                <module>../module5</module>
            </modules>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <preparationGoals>validate</preparationGoals>
                            <tagBase>http://<svn_ip>:8080/repos/DMC/<project>/tags</tagBase>
                            <useEditMode>true</useEditMode>
                            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                            <updateWorkingCopyVersions>false</updateWorkingCopyVersions>
                            <tagNameFormat>rel-${env.REL_TAG}</tagNameFormat>
                            <username>${env.SCM_USER}</username>
                            <password>${env.SCM_PASSWD}</password>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

I'm running this maven via Jenkins and job fails every second time. When it fails I got following error:

```
[INFO] Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
    com.group.id:module1:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
in project 'module1' (com.group.id:module1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

But on second time the job success. What it can be?

Comment: With which goals and options did you execute Maven? And are you sure that version 2.4 of the maven-release-plugin is used?

Comment: -Pmake-tag release:clean release:prepare  -sbuild/deploy-settings.xml -Dresume=false

Comment: This is not enough information to reproduce the issue. What happens if you don't use Jenkins for the release, but your own system? If it still happens, create the smallest possible project to reproduce it an create an issue for it at MRELEASE.